# Vlookup to find number of instances two items appear with a pivot table

Tags: pivot, vlookup

Not sure how to work this, but I think a previous post had me on the right track, but I'm stuck in this particular situation.

Sheet1 is raw data (material number in A:A, Created by user in D:D, username in C3). second tab (PVT) is a pivot table documenting the number of occurrences a specific material appears in Sheet1. I need to look at the material in the pivot table, find out how many times user listed in C3 is found next to that material number in Sheet 1.

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!D:D,VLOOKUP("WYGLADALB",A:A,0))
```

This is what I'm currently using, but obviously this isn't correct. Here is a [sample spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AACbDJ8QUTh5ZdE0Uy0brG7SiybviOFKRo8).

Comment: COUNTIFS will help

Comment: When the spreadsheet link is clicked, it says "Join Dropbox to view this file". It would be good to make this open, so people can see it. It would be even better to make this question self-contained, so an external link is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS()`

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!D:D,C3,Sheet1!A:A,"WYGLADALB")
```

Comment: Both answers didn't work...I'll see if I can figure out how to send an example spreadsheet.